# Call ngAfterViewInit of Angular component from common place

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am using bootstrap tooltip.
I want to trigger ngAfterViewInit for every component from some common place.

Common place(like app.module.ts)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }
```

Component_1: 
There is no ngAfterViewInit in component, still life cycle is trigger from some common place.

Component_2:
This component has ngAfterViewInit,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Some extra functionality
  }
```

In this case ngAfterViewInit is triggered from both the places(common place as well as from it's respective component)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) is an interface, just extends from a component class and use wherever you want to use

Comment: *A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view. Define a ngAfterViewInit() method to handle any additional initialization tasks.* so each component has there owned responsibility

Answer (score 0):

There isn't "one common place" where you can define a global behavior for all of your components.

Instead, you can create the following class and make your desired components extend it:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  /**
   * View initialization behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement AfterViewInit .
   * Use viewInit() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Your code
    this.viewInit();
  }

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define an additional view initialization behavior
   */
  abstract viewInit(): void;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I want some common place from where I can all the ngAfterViewInit. Not only from component. I want extra hook or listener.

Comment: @Ankur please take a look at my new answer